# Create list of dictionaries when key value is greater than 0

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary of movie data and I want to create a new dictionary with a subset of the movies that have values greater than 0.0 for both budget and revenue keys.

Here's my code, can anyone assist?

```
movies_bud_rev = {}
for movie in movie_data:
    if (movie_data['revenue'] != 0.0 or movie_data['budget'] != 0.0):
        id = movie_data['id']
        budget = movie_data['budget']   
        revenue = movie_data['revenue']
        original_title = movie_data['original_title']
        release_year = movie_data['release_year']
        genre = movie_data['genre']
        popularity = movie_data['popularity']
        vote_average = movie_data['vote_average']
        vote_count = movie_data['vote_count']

len (movies_bud_rev)
```

The error that I receive:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

My dictionary
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvBZ9.png)

My attempt at creating the new dictionary
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smsUo.png)

Comment: Please post code in your question, not as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the image you have provided, `movie_data` is a [list of dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44886692/9209546).

Therefore, you need to filter *as a list*. You can achieve this via a list comprehension.

```
res = [m for m in movie_data if (m['revenue'] > 0 and m['budget'] > 0)]
```

Note some issues:

- The result will also be a list of dictionaries.
- The logic that revenue and budget are greater than zero needs to use `and`, not `or`.

Comment: what if revenue is -1, hehe.  `if m['revenue'] > 0`

Comment: @lava-lava, good point - updated. I thought user wanted non-zero for some reason. Also (maybe I'm being dim), how can revenue be negative? Revenue = sales can only be positive, right?

Comment: I'm new to python coding, thank you for the help. I didn't think about negative numbers; that point is very helpful. I'm just not certain how to use the "res = ...." in my code.  Should it be part of my if statement somehow?

Answer (score 0):

As per image you posted `movie_data` is list which contains dictionary
and you were using  index in `movie_data` that's why you getting error instead in `movie` which is dictionary object

```
movies_bud_rev = {}
for movie in movie_data:
    if (movie['revenue'] != 0.0 or movie['budget'] != 0.0):
        id = movie['id']
        budget = movie['budget']   
        revenue = movie['revenue']
        original_title = movie['original_title']
        release_year = movie['release_year']
        genre = movie['genre']
        popularity = movie['popularity']
        vote_average = movie['vote_average']
        vote_count = movie['vote_count']
```

Comment: fixed the indentation

Comment: Thanks.  This resolved my error, but I didn't capture any records either.  So more work for me to do.

Comment: for further you can try , if it worked  please do accept the answers .